# gotoxy() user defined function in c++

Tags: c++

i have read in my course that gotxy() is a predefined function but it is not working on Microsoft visual 2013.so I do some search and i got that piece of code which work will but i have to understand it.So can any one explain it in detail.

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
HANDLE hConsoleOutput;
COORD dwCursorPosition;

cout.flush();
dwCursorPosition.X = x;
dwCursorPosition.Y = y;
hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsoleOutput, dwCursorPosition);
}
```

Comment: `dwCursorPosition` is just a coordinate POD that needs to be sent to [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx). So, you flush the console output buffer, get the POD ready; return the handle to the console output and the set the position on the window using SetConsoleCursorPosition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your course material is about 3 decades out of date, I'd assume, and targets DOS, not even Windows 1.0.

Anyway, the function that you have now is an implementation that still works on modern Windows systems, even though it too is about 20 years out of date.

The first line defines `HANDLE hConsoleOutput;`. It fails to initialize the variable, which should be done like this: `HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);`. This handle is needed later on.

The second line defines the coordinate position `COORD dwCursorPosition;`. Same problem, it should have been initialized: `COORD dwCursorPosition = { x,y };`

`cout.flush()` makes sure that all old output prior to the call is written at the old cursor location.

The next three statements are fixing the uninitialized variables and shouldn't have been necessary if that was done properly. Finally the last call does the real work of telling Windows where to print next.